# Arch linux hip error

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu, linux

I have installed rocm-hip-runtime from the AUR to implement HIP support for my AMD GPU and my GPU shows up in blender's hip settings, but I get this error when I try rendering:

```
HIP hipcc compiler not found. Install hip toolkit in default location
```

This is an issue with rendering with HIP in blender
[image: Hip is enabled]

[image: Gpu is set as render device]

[image: Blender in render mode]

Answer (score -1):

The [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Blender#HIP_on_AMD_open_source_drivers) suggests adding "/opt/rocm/bin/" to your PATH.

You could test by running `env PATH="${PATH}:/opt/rocm/bin/" blender` from the terminal.

This should allow your machine to compile the "HIP kernel" that Blender uses. To add the environment variable permanently see the arch wiki. If this does not work you may need more of the ROCM / HIP installed.

Please save you work before testing Blender as it will probably [lockup your system](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/2145)